# MVC6 Social Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I am currently building a web application with ASP.NET core MVC6 and using the new Identity model. Unfortunately there isn't a lot of documentation on the subject right now and I would like to implement social authentication. What would be the best approach at figuring out how I can go about implementing this functionality with MVC6/Identity?

Comment: there is documentation here https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/sociallogins.html

Answer (score 1):

Like Joe Audette mention there is quite good documentation: [Enabling authentication using external providers](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/sociallogins.html).

There is example for Facebook, but the same way you can add Microsoft, Google and Twitter - just add providers via NuGet Package (`Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication*`) - or you can use general OAuth 2.0 provider with any other client supporting OAuth 2.0

*but please note that mentioned by me OAuth 2.0 provider can have unexpected impact for other provider especially when you set `CallbackPath` - don't ask why, because I don't know yet.*

As for now I use only Microsoft and Google providers and both works well with default settings - below you can find my example with scopes which I use:

```
Startup.cs
...

app.UseIdentity();

// External Authentication
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = Configuration["OAuth:Google:ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["OAuth:Google:ClientSecret"];
    options.AutomaticAuthenticate = false;
    options.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
    options.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");
    //options.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me");
    //options.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");
});

app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(options =>
{
   options.ClientId = Configuration["OAuth:MicrosoftAccount:ClientId"];
   options.ClientSecret = Configuration["OAuth:MicrosoftAccount:ClientSecret"];
   options.AutomaticAuthenticate = false;
   options.Scope.Add("wl.emails");
   options.Scope.Add("wl.basic");
   //options.Scope.Add("wl.phone_numbers");
   //options.Scope.Add("wl.signin");
   //options.Scope.Add("wl.offline_access");
});

...
```

**More about scopes:**

- [Microsoft Account / Windows Live OAuth 2.0 Scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243646.aspx)
- [OAuth 2.0 Scopes for Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes)

Comment: How can I then retrieve claims from external provider and prefill registration form?